# How do I extract data from an HTML page using Perl I've tried every suggestion on this web site and failed

Tags: perl

How can I extract data from an HTML page I've tried everything including suggestions on this web site, such as table extracts, but nothing works. I'm trying to extract option information from a web site that has eight headings and eight columns so I tried the suggested post:

```
use HTML::TableExtract;  
use LWP::Simple;

my $html_string = get('http://www.barchart.com/commodityfutures/Australian_Dollar_Futures/options/A6');

$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(Strike Open High Low Current Change Time     Prem ($) )] ); 
$te->parse($html_string) or die "Didn't find table"; 

foreach $row ($te->rows) { 
    print join(',', @$row), "\n"; 
}
```

but this didn't work any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You will need to give more information than "it didn't work" if anybody is to help you. What happened?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the column headings don't match the ones in the table :) It might look like they do but, if you do:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$a = [qw(Strike Open High Low Current Change Time     Prem ($) )];
print Dumper($a);
```

You get:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'Strike',
      'Open',
      'High',
      'Low',
      'Current',
      'Change',
      'Time',
      'Prem',
      '($)'
    ];
```

Note the final two columns. What you probably need is:

```
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers =>  [ "Strike", "Open", "High", "Low",
    "Current", "Change", "Time", "Prem (\$)" ] );
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, but that didn't work. I finally found another suggestion that did work:  #use warnings; 
use HTML::TableExtract; 
use YAML; 
use Data::Dumper;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( ); 
$te->parse_file('barChart.html'); 
my $table = $te->first_table_found();

#for my $table ( $te->tables ) { 
#print Dumper $table->columns; 
#} 

foreach my $ts ($te->tables) {
          print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
          foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
             print join(',', @$row), "\n";
          }
        }

Comment: @AmbroseZaragoza you should have added that as an answer yourself and accepted it. Why do you need `YAML` btw?

Answer (score 0):

In the following way one can extract html data of any webpage using perl:

```
#!perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $URL= "http://urladdress";
my $content = get($URL);
print $content;
```